# error occur when i trying to use Spark on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, rdd

when i use rdd fucntion on ec2, (bin/pyspark)

this error occur

data was
data=sc.textFile("/root/lab/irisdata")
or
data=sc.textFile("s3n://" + bucket.name+"/" + file_key.name")

```
    15/08/27 09:16:58 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/08/27 09:16:58 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1247, in take
    totalParts = self.getNumPartitions()
  File "/root/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 355, in getNumPartitions
    return self._jrdd.partitions().size()
  File "/root/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/root/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23.partitions.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://ec2-54-65-212-78.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/root/lab/irisdata
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

plz let me know how do i fix it.

ps. in local computer, same code no error :(

Comment: you datafile, "/root/lab/irisdata" is not located on spark master, does the workers need the file? (most of cases they do, for any serialized processing), either put it on S3 and load it in from S3, or put it on hdfs. Do not copy it onto the local on the master, it usually does not work. (even if you use SparkFiles.get in your code, it does not work on S3 for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
Input path does not exist: hdfs://ec2-54-65-212-78.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/root/lab/irisdata
```

indicates that the file you're attempting to read into an rdd is not where you think it is. Looks like it's not in the local filesystem but instead in hdfs.